# Elastic APM transaction timeline is missing

Tags: kibana, elastic-apm

I'm enthusiatic user of Elastic APM for several years and I am running Elastic APM on Kibana 7.15.0 to analyse web services written in Java and Python.
Recently I found that Timeline pane in Transactions menu doesn't show spans for SQL, Redis etc.
I went through kibana log but no proviso related with this omission was appeared.

[span missing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhMAM.png)

I need elastic APM but I am lack of sufficient knowledge to operate it well..

Comment: Seems like it would be worth an issue on the agent (Python or Java) that's showing the issue. SQL and Redis spans should be captured unless you're using a very niche library that isn't instrumented by the agent.

Comment: I found span indices had not saved since 3 weeks before posting. Other indices like transaction, metrics have been saved well. It's very odd.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/issues/1482), which has since been fixed.

Can you update to the [latest version](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/releases/tag/v6.8.1) of the python agent and see if the spans are back?